# Dictation bug: variations of 'catch' appear without being spoken anything

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation, ios

Strangely, on my iPhone 11 with latest iOS 13 updates, an annoying bug has crept in. If i use dictation, which I do all day, the word “catch” or variations of it will pop into the message. Frequently this occurs even if nothing has been said. And I can’t speak a paragraph without “catch” showing up in there.

A little paranoia creeps in, and it has me wondering if some kind of surveillance monitoring is involved, like someone is initiating a command of “catch” which is causing my text to to recorded lol. I realize that is probably just crazy talk!

Any idea what’s what the problem/solution might be?

Comment: It started about 3 days ago and I’ve had the phone since Iphone 11 launch day

Comment: Identical issue for me. Still happening and quite frustrating if not creepy. Onset of mental illness in the AI world?

Comment: Put on your tin foil hats and get ready for [ultrasonic dolphin attack](https://www.engadget.com/2017/09/06/alexa-and-siri-are-vulnerable-to-silent-nefarious-commands/) theories!

Answer (score 1):

A few users over in the Apple support community discussion group have brought up this problem within the past week. It has everybody stumped over there too. 
Other than your post here, and the three or four posters over there, I haven’t seen much noise being raised about this bug. 
The way it is driving it’s victims crazy, I expect this bug will raise the noise level enough to get even apples attention.
 As for me, it’s making my iPhone nearly unusable. I can’t find any way to make it happen or to make it stop happening. I can barely believe that I have dictated this entire long post without the word catch being inserted somewhere.